# What order of iptables rules to use for specific SRC IPs?

Tags: iptables

I would like to block traffic from a specific address during some hours. I use [`firehol`](https://firehol.org/) to manage my rules.

The following rule does block all traffic during my target hours

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere          anywhere             ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED TIME from 06:00:00 to 16:00:00 UTC
```

The same rule modified for a specific IP

```
ACCEPT     all  --  10.10.10.21          anywhere             ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED TIME from 06:00:00 to 16:00:00 UTC
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
```

does not block the traffic for `10.10.10.21`. The order looks correct (from more specific to more general) so I wonder what could be missing?

(please note that this is just the extract from `iptables -L` relevant to the time limitation - the rules which change when adding a specific rule for a specific IP (as opposed to the -working- rule which block all traffic outside of the mentioned hours)

Comment: The rules you show are `ACCEPT`-rules they will never block anything.

Comment: @Henrik Yes, but the rule is time-bound and is not applied outside of the mentioned hours (so since the default is to reject, they effectively block outside of that time)

Comment: Okay, then your problem is that the last rule accepts anything at any time, you'll need to add something like `! -s 10.10.10.21` to it.

Comment: But shouldn't the more specific rule match and others not be processed further?

Comment: But the specific rule *doesn't* match outside the time range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have ACCEPT rules but some traffic ends up being blocked, it means that your rule's policy is DROP. So your first attempt denies all traffic that isn't explicitly authorized. Your second attempt *also* denies all traffic that isn't explicitly authorized, but the second rule allows most traffic (it only blocks a few things that should be allowed through, such as ICMP errors — you should always allow `RELATED` through).

The first match applies. Rule 1 allows traffic from 10.10.10.21 during a certain time window. Rule 2 allows (almost) all traffic at all times. Since rule 1 is a subset of rule 2, it's redundant.

To deny traffic from 10.10.10.21 outside the specified time window, you need to either modify rule 2 to exclude traffic from 10.10.10.21, or add a rule in between that denies traffic. I think the second option is clearer.

```
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -s 10.10.10.21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -m time --timestart 06:00:00 --timestop 16:00
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT -s 10.10.10.21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

Note that [you should almost always use REJECT on blocked traffic, not DROP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject). You can't set a chain policy to DROP, which is why I added an explicit REJECT rule at the end.